# Addition Algorithm for Quote Notation

Tags: algorithm, notation

I am working through understanding [Quote Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quote_notation) and am trying to build a simple quote calculator in Python. I have the conversions to and from floats, and am now trying to understand some of the arithmetic. In trying to code up a function that can add two quotes together, I find I am lost. The linked Wikipedia entry reads "In quote notation, to add, just add," which is frustratingly unhelpful. Even in the examples they give, I can't find a way to add the quotes together without converting them back to floats, which defeats the purpose.

What is an algorithm that can adding two quote numbers together, without converting to floats? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"To add, just add" is a correct description, but leaves out a pragmatically important termination condition. (It also does not make explicit the fact that the numbers must first be aligned at their radix points, probably because the authors of the original paper felt that procedure to be implicit in "just add".)

Recall that the digits previous to the quote are to be thought of as repeating infinitely to the left. To add two numbers, we just work right to left in the normal fashion.

If we did that naively, the algorithm would never finish since the implicit representation is infinite. But its output must eventually start cycling, because it is effectively a finite-state machine. That is, once we're on the left-hand side of the quote, the state of the sum algorithm is completely determined by:

- the index in the first addend;
- the index in the second addend;
- and the carry (0 or 1).

The number of possible states is at most twice the product of the two cycle lengths (more precisely, it is twice the least common multiple of the cycle lengths). Since there is a finite number of states, some state must repeat, and that implies that the rest of the sequence is cyclic.

You could use something like the [tortoise and hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) algorithm to find a repeated state with O(1) additional memory. Howeve, that doesn't find the shortest representation. Once you find a cyclic prefix, and you must then normalise the number by shifting that cycle right as far as possible. (You can shift the cycle right if the first digit is the same as the digit after the quote; if so, drop the first digit, shift the quote one position to the right, and repeat until the digits differ.)

Comment: When adding the numbers together in a digit-by-digit fashion, how should the operands be aligned? By their quote marks, or by their radix points?

Comment: @TheNewGuy: By their radix points, as usual. The quotes just tell you where to repeat the digits from when you get to the start of the representation.

Comment: How would you, for example add 9' to 9'0 to get 9'89? (That being -1 + -10 = -11 in standard notation.)

Comment: @TheNewGuy: Conceptually you have  `...99999` + `...99990`. You add from right to left, 0+9=9 carry 0; 9+9+0=8 carry 1; 9+9+1=9 carry 1; 9+9+1=9 carry 1 / state repeats. Since we've found a repeated state, we know the result is  `...9989`, and we need to find the shortest repetition, which is obviously `9`; thus, we write the number with that repetition followed by a quote: `9'89`.

Comment: @TheNewGuy: If both addends are integers, then there will only be one digit before the quote in both addends and also in the result. That makes detecting the end of the sum much easier, but the full algorithm has to work with fractions, too, which is why some kind of cycle detector is needed. In the integer case, the cycle detector will tell us the cycle has length 1. We can start the quote after the cycle we just found of length one (`9'989`) and then shift it right using the algorithm I noted in my answer until we achieve a normalised result.

Comment: @TheNewGuy: did you not understand my description of the algorithm as indicating that? Perhaps I need to edit it....

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that the integer case is a simple generalisation of 2's-complement. Instead of numbers having a sign bit at a fix place, they conceptually start with an infinite stream of sign bits, which we economise by the convention that the first bit is infinitely repeated. Addition is then  ordinary 2's-complement addition, except that we keep on repeating the sign bits as necessary until we emit two consecutive identical bits (both derived from sign bits) Then we can normalise the representation by reducing the initial sequence of identical bits to a single sign bit.

Comment: I am confident there must be some way of calculating ahead of time how many digits will appear to the left of the quote of the sum, without having to engage a cycle detection algorithm. For example, if each operand has only one such digit, we know we are adding together multiples of 1/9 and therefore the sum can't have more than one digit to the left of its quote.

Comment: @TheNewGuy: You can easily compute a maximum, but it might be very large. Cycle detection is very cheap. (The cycle detection comes from Horspool & Hehner's original paper, by the way, although they suggest Brent's algorithm.)

Comment: H&H provide formulas for the upper bound in section 7.1 of their paper, but they add "This  approach  obviates  the  need  to  recognize  a  repeated  state.  However,  the  complexity  of  our formulae  for the  length bounds  makes  the  approach unattractive." However, they do not propose a normalisation algorithm afaics, and the digit cycle might be shorter than the state cycle. It is possible to find the shortest cycle in a necklace in linear time, although the algorithm is apparently not as well known.